# How to remove style attribute from tags?

Tags: javascript, html

I'm creating a mobile version of an website and to make it work good I need to remove "style" attributes from certain tags all over the page.

Example:

```
 <div class="gallery-arrows" style="top:85px;"></div><h8 style="top:85px;"><a href="https://twitter.com/TeamTHCRacing" style="color:#ffffff;">THC Racing on Twitter!</a></h8>
```

and i need to be:

```
 <div class="gallery-arrows"></div><h8><a href="https://twitter.com/TeamTHCRacing" style="color:#ffffff;">THC Racing on Twitter!</a></h8>
```

Is there something i could add to remove them? Like a script or something?

Thanks!

Comment: See the [removeAttribute() method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element.removeAttribute)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using jquery it's simple:

```
$('div,h8,a').removeAttr("style");
```

Comment: Not just `$('[style]').removeAttr("style")`?

Comment: The question was "certain tags"..So i mentioned the tags otherwise your method is excellent.